# How to send an email to a java program

Tags: java

I'd like to write a program, probably a servlet or something to run on the a google app engine that I can send an email to. So not a program to send email, but one that can receieve it and parse it.

My question is, what code or API are out there that can receive an email?

Comment: "Dear program…" :)
Well, your program should just poll mailserver and retrieve the mail. keywords are pop or imap.

Comment: You cant just recieve email on a socket... its a rather complex matter.  You need DNS setup with MX records... or something needs to point directly at the service and you can write a POP or IMAP server.  Your best bet is to setup a mailbox for the app on some service then the app can check the mailbox (pop, imap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically on your google app engine you can use an inbound mail service.

Please see this documentation for more information.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html#Receiving_Mail_in_Java

Answer (score 0):

You cant send an email to a program, you send an email to a server, so what you are looking for is a way to access an email server via your program. Unfortunately there is no single solution here, you need to configure your program for every different email account/server you want to access. (If you have ever set up an account in outlook or something like it you will get the idea)

For example here is a link to the gmail api, you could use this to access gmail accounts
http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a mailbox to send message there and you could read messages with the code like this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/GetEmailMessageExample.htm

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a built in Java library.

`javax.mail`

Check out [this link](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/package-summary.html). It should be able to help you get started.

This won't work for every mail server, but depending on your setup it might help.

Answer (score 0):

To send an email to a Java program, that program must be running.  Generally that means a server style (aka service) receiver is favored.

For the email to be received, the Java service must understand an email protocol.  There are a number of protocols, but SMTP is the standard for receiving email.  Once you have a service that understands SMTP protocol for receiving email, you have written a mail server.

Note that most people don't care to write a mail server, as a mail client needs to connect to the server and pull the email to make it readable.  Keep this in mind when designing the solution to your problem.